# Connect node.js server with python client to send messages. The client connects but it's not able to send messages to the server

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

class Namespace(BaseNamespace):
    def on_aaa_response(self, *args):
        print('on_aaa_response', args)
        self.emit('bbb')

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 3000, Namespace)
def on_connect():
    print('Connected')


socketIO.on('connect', on_connect)
socketIO.on('chatmessage', on_message)
socketIO.wait(seconds=1000)
```

How do i  connect with node.js server so that i can send commands between a python client and a node.js client? 
HERE is my code for the server
please suggest changes for it.
or is anybody having a similar project link?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){ console.log('a user connected');
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('user disconnected');
});
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('chatmessage', function(msg){
io.emit('chatmessage', msg);
});
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('chatmessage', function(msg){
console.log('message: ' + msg);
});
});
io.emit('some event', { for: 'everyone' });
http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: @cricket_007 please have a look at it

Comment: So, have you tried the "hello world" Javascript client on the documentation? Could you send messages with that?

Comment: why you are listening both servers on 3000 ports?